# Does the "come" in "come a certain time-point" need to conjugate according to verb tense?

Tags: word-usage, tenses

If I am talking about a past event, e.g., a wedding, do I say "Come the wedding day, everyone was hyped about the ginormous wedding cake." or "Came the wedding day, everyone was hyped about the ginormous wedding cake."?

Comment: What do the omission dots stand for? It'd be helpful if you could post a complete sentence.

Comment: @Nico Thank you for the remainder. I have thus removed them.

Comment: To me, such constructions with inversions are not entrenched. One would rather say "as the wedding day came...".

Comment: @Nico I just want to know the conjugation rules of this structure, whether it is the recommended use in this sentence is not the point.

Comment: No offence meant, but I would recommend getting familiar with the notion of  "conjugation", which has nothing to do with your question at all.

Comment: @Nico I just learned that "come" here is actually a preposition, so you are probably right.

Comment: "Come the wedding day" = when the wedding day comes. Not a preposition. And for me, it's a spoken form used in storytelling.

Answer (score 1):

"Come" in this construct is in the subjunctive. Fowler, in Modern English Usage (2nd ed.), s.v. *subjunctives*, gives the example "I shall be 70 come Tuesday".

This "come" is certainly not a preposition. It can't be coordinated with a preposition.

*Before and come the wedding-day, ...

*Come and after the wedding-day, ...

are syntactically impossible.

Comment: Nevertheless, [Lexico:  'come'](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/come) is listed as a preposition for that usage.

Comment: As Einstein said, "*Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler.*"

Comment: @Rosie F: The OED agrees with you on the subjunctive: ++ **Come (v.) 34. intransitive. In the subjunctive. Chiefly colloquial and regional.** ++ ***(b) Without a stated period of time or age.*** ++ 1868   Every Sat. 19 Sept. 368/2  *Come six o'clock, they were to turn into their cells.* ++ 2016   E. Martinez in Eat Pray Love made me do it 36  *Come year's end, I was on a career high.*

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar construction *"Cometh the time, cometh the man."* in which Cometh is the obsolete third person singular.

What is happening in both *"Come/Came the wedding day,"* and *"Cometh the time,"* is that there is an omitted relative adverb-conjunction = "**When**" *(often, **especially in older English** coupled with **... then**)*

The saying *"Cometh the time, cometh the man"* is thus to be understood as **When** the (political) time (circumstances) arrives, **then** the man (i.e. leader) arrives.

The same is true of your: *"Came the wedding day, everyone was amazed..."* - "***When*** the wedding day arrived, everyone was amazed..."

In earlier English, it would have been "***When came*** the wedding day, **then was** everyone amazed..."

This is caused by the inversion of subject and verb after a fronting adverb, e.g.

*Dearly did I love her*

*Hardly had he arrived*

*So do I*

*Neither do I**

NB This inversion is sometimes used and sometimes it is not.

(As an aside, this effect of inversion caused by an adverb also explains why questions have an inverted form: "Why was he in China?" "When did he go?", "Where is he now?")

The same is true of your examples:

"Came the wedding day, everyone was amazed..." - "**When** the wedding day arrived, **then** everyone was amazed..."

However, there is another grammatical effect that influence the first example.

The use of "Come" and "was" in he same sentence must be explained: "**Come** the wedding day, everyone **was** hyped."

[Edit: For the mood of the verb, see Rosie F below]

Comment: Thank you very much, but I googled it and found out that when used like this, "come" is actually a preposition. In addition, if it is inversion caused by an adverb-first sentence order, then there is an adverb missing before "come/came", so maybe it can also be understood as an inversion with an omitted adverb just as you indicated?

Comment: @Jaden Wong *"come" is actually a preposition."* That is incorrect. *In addition, if it is inversion caused by an adverb-first sentence order,* That is what I said.  *it can also be understood as an inversion with an omitted adverb just as you indicated* ++That is the case.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/92945/prepositional-usage-of-come It turns out another person asked about the same use a while ago.

Comment: That answer needs correcting. It would be convenient to call "come" a preposition, but it would be wrong. The use of "come July/your birthday,etc" has a long history in English and "come" is always a verb. As Einstein said, "*Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler.*"

Comment: Rosie, below, gives an answer disagreeing with your first analysis. She adds a supporting reference. Your answer sounds very plausible, but **needs** supporting evidence to stand up against hers. Especially since CGEL [7.5.1] considers 'come' in this usage to have undergone full conversion to a preposition (thus not inflecting): << 'Come' takes a future [from the time under consideration] time expression as complement: _Come the end of the year, we should be free of all these debts_. Historically,

Comment: this is a subjunctive clausal construction, with come a plain form verb and the end of the year its subject; synchronically, however, its function and internal structure are like those of a PP (compare by the end of the year), and it is plausible to suggest that come has been reanalysed as a preposition. // Personally, I think that that isn't precise enough; 'Cometh the hour, ...' and 'Came the X, ...' are certainly still to be found.